# jQuery delay post data into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-post, delay

I have this function in jQuery that gets data from a page with POST, then sets the response into a div:

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
   $.post("get.php", {p: 'abc'}, function(data){ 
   $('#result').html(data); 
   });
});
```

This works, but is there anyway to delay the data going into the `#result` tag by about 3 seconds?

Eventually I want the tag to say:

"Loading.", "Loading..", and "Loading..." for a second each, then show the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
   // Show loader here
   $.post("get.php", {p: 'abc'}, function(data){ 
       setTimeout(function () {
           // Hide loader here
           $('#result').html(data);
       }, 3000); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the syntax you should use.

```
var delayCounter = 3;
var delayTimer = '';
delayTimer = setInterval(function(){
  if (delayCounter > 0){
    $('#result').html('Loading...');
  }else{
    $('#result').html(data);
    clearInterval(delayTimer);
  }
  delayCounter--;
},1000);
```

Whats happening here?

- We use the `delayCounter` variable to count how many times we have delayed the action.  Its starting value is 3 - so we will be "delayed" 3 times.
- The `delayTimer` variable is the timer itself that will count each delay.
- We use the `setInterval` function becuase that is exactly what we are wanting to do - set intervals between executing our code.
- The `clearInterval` is pretty self explanatory - this ends and clears the timer.
- For each iteration we *decrease* the `delayCounter` variable so that we can keep track of how many intervals have passed.
- We use miliseconds to define the delay - here I have used 1000 which is 1 seconds (1000 milliseconds in one second).

One more addition you might like to implement is that instead of simply placing the "Loading" text in your element, to make it a little bit more dynamic by appending text to it.
What might be fun is to append the ellipsis to the word "Loading" to get an effect like :

[image]

First set the initial value to "Loading" then append each dot -

```
$('#result').html($('#result').html()+'.');
// Loading
// Loading.
// Loading..
// Loading...
```

<sub>That said you could also just take the animated gif and use that [lazy-programmers](/questions/tagged/lazy-programmers)  :P</sub>

Comment: Geeees - that's taking **FOREVER** to load!!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#result').html(data);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit: updated to add loading functionality.

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
   $.post("get.php", {p: 'abc'}, function(data){ 
   window.intervalTimer = setInterval(function(data) {
       if (!window.timeoutCount)
            window.timeoutCount = 0;

            if (++window.timeoutCount > 3) {
                $('#result').html(data);
                clearInterval(window.intervalTimer);
             }
            else
                  $('#result').html("Loading..")
    }, 1000); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To delay the execution of a function in JavaScript use the [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout) method. Works a little like:

```
var doLater = setTimeout(function(){
alert('I like to wait 5 seconds');
},5000); //delay is stated in ms
```

In your case that would end up in:

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
   $.post("get.php", {p: 'abc'}, function(data){ 
   var wait = setTimeout(function(){$('#result').html(data);},3000); 
   });
});
```

Comment: -1 Your `setInterval` is never cleared.  Detailing the `clearInterval` function is defiantly needed when explaining  `setInterval`.

Comment: @lix: Oh I'm terribly sorry, didn't mean to write what I actually wrote

Comment: I also get confused sometimes between them! Removed -1, and upvoted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#go").click(function(){ 
  $.post("get.php", {p: 'abc'}, function(data) {  
    $('go').html('Loading.');
    setTimeout("function() {
      $('go').html('Loading..');
    }",1000);
    setTimeout("function() {
      $('go').html('Loading...');
    }",1000);
    $('#result').html(data); 
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 A little too verbose for my liking :P  But it should work!